Php8.1-pgsql package is not found
I am trying to create a docker compose image file with php8.1, but I am getting this error.
I am trying to build image for Laravel server. I have tried running the Dockerfile as root as well.
How can I fix this, turns out php8.1 uses Debian base image.
I have tried

using www-user from base image and then its says permissions error
using root user I get package not found error. But in ubuntu server that i am using I am finding the package from apt.
If I try to add php apt repository it bring up error of public key

FROM serversideup/php:8.1-fpm-nginx

ENV SSL_MODE "off"

USER root

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git curl wget php8.1-pgsql libxrender1 cron fonts-freefont-ttf  \
    && apt autoclean && apt autoremove \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

USER www-data

COPY --chown=webuser:webgroup . /var/www/html/

RUN composer install
RUN composer du
RUN chown -R webuser:webgroup .

RUN chmod +x ./scripts/start.sh
RUN sh ./scripts/start.sh


ubuntu@ip-172-31-0-58:~/Morgenland-Search-Backend$ sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
[+] Building 3.5s (6/12)                                                                                                                                                                         docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.prod                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 523B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for docker.io/serversideup/php:8.1-fpm-nginx                                                                                                                              0.4s
 => CACHED [app 1/8] FROM docker.io/serversideup/php:8.1-fpm-nginx@sha256:812c9d05672415f88b0d9ec7a871d50f30c6a8bfae6ea01f6da363c0bc822c38                                                                 0.0s
 => [app internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => => transferring context: 321.85kB                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => ERROR [app 2/8] RUN apt update     && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git curl wget php8.1-pgsql libxrender1 cron fonts-freefont-ttf      && apt autoclean && apt autoremove     && rm -rf /tm  3.1s
------
 > [app 2/8] RUN apt update     && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git curl wget php8.1-pgsql libxrender1 cron fonts-freefont-ttf      && apt autoclean && apt autoremove     && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*:
0.300
0.300 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
0.300
0.329 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
0.330 Get:2 http://nginx.org/packages/debian bookworm InRelease [2860 B]
0.338 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
0.338 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
0.391 Get:5 http://nginx.org/packages/debian bookworm/nginx amd64 Packages [7975 B]
0.463 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8786 kB]
0.539 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [13.8 kB]
0.585 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [158 kB]
1.409 Fetched 9223 kB in 1s (8465 kB/s)
1.409 Reading package lists...
2.004 Building dependency tree...
2.164 Reading state information...
2.190 5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
2.195
2.195 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
2.195
2.198 Reading package lists...
2.780 Building dependency tree...
2.932 Reading state information...
2.958 E: Unable to locate package php8.1-pgsql
2.958 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-pgsql'
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt update     && apt install -y --no-install-recommends git curl wget php8.1-pgsql libxrender1 cron fonts-freefont-ttf      && apt autoclean && apt autoremove     && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100



add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php seems to have failed. Also, that docker image is based on Debian, not Ubuntu, which makes the comparison with your Ubuntu server moot. In any case, instead of using sudo, you can add the user to the docker group. Also, it would perhaps help if you extracted a [mcve] and checked whether the Docker cache had any influence.

Are you sure this is the error output for that Dockerfile? The logs fail on a single RUN statement containing apt update && apt install ..... but your Dockerfile contains separate RUN statements for apt update and apt-get install ....

Yes, it used to work till few days ago. And I am getting this error later.
